# Resolving imports using webpack's worker-loader in Jest tests

Tags: webpack, loader, jestjs, worker

I'm writing a Jest test and am having trouble resolving this import which uses webpack's `worker-loader`

```
import ImageInfoWorker from 'worker-loader?name=image_info!@WORKERS/image-info';
```

I have some other aliases which are resolving properly in my tests, such as:

```
import Store from '@SUPPORT/store';
import * as api from '@SUPPORT/api';
```

Here is the relevant snippet from `package.json`

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "jsx"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@CSS/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/css/$1",
      "^@COMPONENTS/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/js/components/$1",
      "^@MODELS/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/js/models/$1",
      "^@STORES/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/js/stores/$1",
      "^@SUPPORT/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/js/support/$1",
      "^(.*?)@WORKERS/(.*)$": "$1<rootDir>/js/workers/$2"
  }
}
```

And here is the `resolve` section of my webpack config:

```
        resolve: {
          extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
          modules: [process.env.NODE_PATH, 'node_modules'],
          alias: {
            '@CSS':        path.join(projectRoot, 'css'),
            '@COMPONENTS': path.join(projectRoot, 'js', 'components'),
            '@MODELS':     path.join(projectRoot, 'js', 'models'),
            '@STORES':     path.join(projectRoot, 'js', 'stores'),
            '@SUPPORT':    path.join(projectRoot, 'js', 'support'),
            '@WORKERS':    path.join(projectRoot, 'js', 'workers')
        }
      },
```

Comment: did u find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @JuHwon No, we haven't.

Comment: Not enough informations. Are you sure you are running webpack on tests? The issue is the worker-loader is webpack stuff so you really need build before tests. Also jest runs in node and node doesn't have workers, so you need need set worker as inline, build everything with webpack and run tests.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker ? This works for normal Worker. I am not sure about code using `worker-loader` to import modules.

Comment: I had the same problem with a React app, found the solution [here](https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-a-file-in-jest-that-use-webworker).

Answer (score 6):

If you don't need the path to be resolved, you can use `"moduleNameMapper"` to ignore the import.

First, create an empty module that contains `export default ''`.

Next, add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^worker-plugin/loader.+$": "<rootDir>/EmptyModule"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This [solution](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/worker-loader/issues/10#issuecomment-325977537) worked for me.

Create a workerMock.js file with mocking implementation you need in a folder called `__mocks__`(of course you can create it anywhere you like):

```
module.exports = Object.create(null);
```

Then in your jest config add configuration below:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
  "\\.worker.js":"<rootDir>/__mocks__/workerMock.js"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [cpojer](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3449) web-workers are not supported in Jest. You should use mocking, read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/manual-mocks.html)

Comment: In order to be selected as an answer you would really need to provide a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

This approach worked for me with both inline-style and config-style worker imports.

Webpack-bundled WebWorkers are not suported by Jest yet (not that I know of), so you have to mock the worker. Simply extract the functionality of your worker to an external file, and in the worker file perform just the worker-y bits.

`@WORKERS/imageInfo.js` — the “meat” of your worker:

```
export default imageInfoFunction(data) {
    //...
}
```

`@WORKERS/imageInfo.worker.js`, the worker gravy:

```
import imageInfoFunction from "./imageInfo";

self.onmessage = async function (e) {
  self.postMessage(imageInfoFunction(e.data));
};
```

This way you can mock just the Worker part of your implementation, while testing the actual functionality:

`mocks/imageInfo.worker.js`

```
import imageInfoFunction from "@WORKERS/imageInfo";

export default class ImageInfoWorker {
  constructor() {
    // should be overwritten by the code using the worker
    this.onmessage = () => { };
  }

  // mock expects data: { } instead of e: { data: { } }
  postMessage(data) {
    // actual worker implementation wraps argument into { data: arg },
    // so the mock needs to fake it 
    this.onmessage({ data: imageInfoFunction (data) });
  }
}
```

Now in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "@WORKERS/(.*\\.worker\\.js)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/$1",
    "@WORKERS/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/js/workers/$1",
  },
};
```

Note I didn't include the inline `worker-loader` config, but I skipped the `^(.*)`. This works because we don't need `worker-loader` anymore since we are mocking the worker. The first path is for .worker.js files that we want to mock and the other is for actual functionality that we want to test. The following would also work:

```
    "^(.*?)@WORKERS/(.*\\.worker\\.js)$": "<rootDir>/mocks/$2",
    "^(.*?)@WORKERS/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/js/workers/$2",
```

This solution could probably be generalized so that all workers are mocked at once, suggestions welcome.

Comment: my @WORKERS/imageInfo.worker.js also has self.importScripts , but it is not getting mocked , any idea how to fix it ?

So my @Workers/imageInfo.worker.js looks like 

import imageInfoFunction from "./imageInfo";
self.importScripts("somescript");

self.onmessage = async function (e) {
  self.postMessage(imageInfoFunction(e.data));
};

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with html-loader. Simplest solution for me was to just mock the import with virtual one:

```js
jest.mock('worker-loader?name=image_info!@WORKERS/image-info', () => ({
  default: {
    // ... mock worker here
  }
}), { virtual: true });
```