# can't import javascript file in vue test utils

Tags: testing, vue.js, vue-component, jestjs, vuex

I am testing one vue file which import Javascript file.

//unlockWallet.worker.js

```
import { Wallet, Configs } from '@/helpers';

function create(password) {
  const createdWallet = {};
  const wallet = new Wallet.generate();
  createdWallet.walletJson = wallet.toV3(password, {
    kdf: Configs.wallet.kdf,
    n: Configs.wallet.n
  });
  createdWallet.name = wallet.getV3Filename();
  return createdWallet;
}

onmessage = function(event) {
  if (event.data.type === 'createWallet') {
    const workerResult = create(event.data.data[0]);
    postMessage(workerResult);
  }
};
```

And PasswordModal.vue I import unlockWallet.worker.js file like this.

```
import Worker from '@/workers/unlockWallet.worker.js'

methods: {
    unlockWallet() {
      const worker = new Worker();
      const self = this;
      worker.postMessage({
        type: 'unlockWallet',
        data: [this.file, this.password]
      });
      worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        // Regenerate the wallet since the worker only return an object instance. Not the whole wallet instance
        self.$store.dispatch(
          'decryptWallet',
          BasicWallet.unlock({
            type: 'manualPrivateKey',
            manualPrivateKey: Buffer.from(e.data._privKey).toString('hex')
          })
        );
      };
    }
```

in PasswordModal.spec.js

```
import {shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'
import PasswordModal from '@/layouts/PasswordModal.vue';
```

And I had failed to pass through this test.

Test suite failed to run
ReferenceError: onmessage is not defined

Comment: From what I see, you don't export anything in your `unlockWallet.worker.js` file, so it won't be defined if you try to import it.

Comment: I have uploaded code. as you can see I could import that file and create Worker object but in testing , I couldn't import even.

Comment: @ThomasLombart Web workers work that way, the whole file is being processed as the worker, you don't write it as a module. The issue lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you're really trying to do is import a Web Worker, not just any JavaScript file, and these only work in the browser.

You might try [jsdom-worker](https://github.com/developit/jsdom-worker), which emulates workers for Node, but I couldn't make it work with Webpack, so if you're using Webpack and its `worker-loader` plugin, you might want to mock the worker altogether for the test.

First separate your functionality out of the worker file into `unlockWallet.js`:

```
import { Wallet, Configs } from '@/helpers';

function create(password) {
  const createdWallet = {};
  const wallet = new Wallet.generate();
  createdWallet.walletJson = wallet.toV3(password, {
    kdf: Configs.wallet.kdf,
    n: Configs.wallet.n
  });
  createdWallet.name = wallet.getV3Filename();
  return createdWallet;
}

export default function(eventData) {
  if (eventData.type === 'createWallet') {
    const workerResult = create(eventData.data[0]);
    postMessage(workerResult);
  }
};
```

Then your worker will just import it. `unlockWallet.worker.js`:

```
import workerFunction from "./unlockWallet.js";

self.onmessage = async function (event) {
  self.postMessage(workerFunction(event.data));
};
```

This way you can mock the worker. `test/mocks/unlockWallet.worker.js`:

```
import workerFunction from "../../src/unlockWallet.js"; // or wherever you keep it

export default class Worker {
  constructor() {
    // should be overwritten by client code
    this.onmessage = () => { };
  }

  // mock expects data: { } instead of e: { data: { } }
  postMessage(data) {
    // actual worker implementation wraps argument arg into { data: arg },
    // so the mock needs to fake it 
    this.onmessage({ data: workerFunction (data) });
  }
}
```

Note that you should set `onmessage` before calling `postMessage`. For a real worker, this won't matter because it's called asynchronously, but our mock is synchronous, therefore in `PasswordModal.vue` it should be:

```
 worker.onmessage = function(e) {
   // ...
 };
 worker.postMessage({
    type: 'unlockWallet',
    data: [this.file, this.password]
  });
```

Related [Resolving imports using webpack's worker-loader in Jest tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567535/resolving-imports-using-webpacks-worker-loader-in-jest-tests).